# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InconsistentGroupProtocolException: The group member's supported protocols are incompatible with those of existing

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm trying to connect to a kafka topic using a spring-boot application and I'm getting this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InconsistentGroupProtocolException: The group member's supported protocols are incompatible with those of existing members or first group member tried to join with empty protocol type or empty protocol list.
```

When I configure my consumer I provide

```
security.protocol = SASL_SSL
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
```

so I have no idea which protocol is missing/empty.
Has anyone solved this problem in the past?

I tried to search the site, but the problems found there did not suit me. For example, partition.assignment.strategy are the same and used by default both on the server and in my spring boot application.

Comment: I have a solution. The reason for this non-informative error was that the name of the Kafka Connect group that publishes messages from Debezium was the same as the `group.id` of the consumer. After renaming the consumer `group.id`, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this non-informative error was that the name of the Kafka Connect group that publishes messages from Debezium was the same as the `group.id` of the consumer. After renaming the consumer `group.id`, the problem is solved.